# How to add image ol.control.ZoomToExtent in openlayers 3?

Tags: openlayers

In ol.control.ZoomToExtent,Openlayers3 use 'E' character for view (http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/examples/navigation-controls.html). But i want to add image.How to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom control as shown in this example.

http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/examples/custom-controls.html

Then you can set the innerHTML of the button with your image using the HTML `<img>` tag.

You'll need to replicate the Zoom to Extent functionality in the click event handler. It can be done using the following line

```
map.getView().fitExtent(newextent,map.getSize())
```

Comment: please check next question http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175839/why-doesnt-show-feature-on-map